# Navigation bar, include with all file

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a site ([www.mhk.me](http://www.mhk.me)). In this site(html) navigation bar focus is change when the page change.
But now I am going make a back-end of this site (Converting on php).
I made a file name(Navigation.php) and then I include with all file.
The problem is that in php site the focus in this is always on HOME not change to other navigation when I change the page.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse nav-main-collapse collapse">
    <div class="container">

        <nav class="nav-main mega-menu">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-main" id="mainMenu">
                <li class="active">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="index.html">
                        Home
                    </a>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="about.html">
                        About Me
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="services.html">
                        Services
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="portfolio.html">
                        Portfolio
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="http://demo.mhk.me">
                        My Templates
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="contact.html">
                        Contact
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do u have a similar page for your footer?

Something like footer.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a script that can compare the url ,so that you can assign .active class to the menu.

```
               $(function() {
                     var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
                .lastIndexOf("/")+1);
                     $(".nav-main li a").each(function(){
                          if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' ){
                          $(this).parent().addClass("active");}
                            if($(this).attr("href") == 'index.php' && pgurl == '' ) {
                            $(this).parent().addClass("active");
                            }
                     })                      
                });
```

Comment: possible to provide me the links that you had the script applied?

Comment: mail me at info@mhk.me I'll give you the complete script.

Comment: Yes I included Jquery.js in Navigation.php.

Comment: @MuhammadHamZaKhan, i need to take a look at the dev page that has the script. do you have one? eg. mhk.me/index.php or mhk.me/about.php

Comment: Yes I have all the files.
Mail me I'll provide you all the files. Then you can check easily, Because I am a JAVASCRIPT beginner.

Comment: nop, please host it temporary on your web server, then provide the link here. sorry for the inconveniences.

Comment: Please put the code I gave you on footer, above your google analytic script. They need to be after the jquery.js.

Answer (score 0):

[Math3w](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4648904/math3w), Your code need to be slightly changed.

```
$(function () {
    var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    $(".nav-main li a").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("href") == pgurl) {
            $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        }
        if ((($(this).attr("href") == 'index.php')||($(this).attr("href") == '')) && (pgurl == '')) {
            $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Still not working :( same like my room A/C. My mind going to blast now.

Comment: @avnaveen, you might have the idea, but usually, Home menu are always linked with index.php or '/', of course you may also need to add '/' in the second .attr("href"). Nice suggestion though. =)

Comment: if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == ' ' )

if we use this, the <a> with an href=' ' and  the <a> with an href = pgurl value with be active.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>ul{
    list-style:none;
}
li{
    cursor:pointer;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:grey;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin:10px;
}
ul>.active{
    background-color:green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body><nav>
    <ul class="nav-main">
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    $(".nav-main li a").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("href") == pgurl) {
            $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        }
        if ((($(this).attr("href") == 'index.php')||($(this).attr("href") == '')) && (pgurl == '')) {
            $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        }
    })
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Save the above code as index.php or about.php or contact.php and check the output.